# SELinux and multiple httpd service context

Tags: centos, apache, redhat, centos6, selinux

Using CentOS 6

I have 2 Apache httpd services running. The first one provides REST interfaces and a UI to manage the operating system (start/stop services, execute system command using suid, modify system settings, etc.). This httpd service (running on port 5555) will only be accessible from a certain ip range (firewall) since it will be used for administrative purposes.

The second httpd service (port 80 and 443) will be visible on the Internet. It will serve a web application to external customers.

The first httpd needs selinux policies that give it more access to the OS files/processes. The second needs selinux policies that are strict to what it is allowed to do within its context. The second needs to be this way for better web application security and prevent any web app exploits from even being able to touch the OS.

Both of the httpd processes are running as different users.

1. Can selinux be used with 2 different sets of policies for the same httpd executable?
2. How do I/is it possible to set the httpd process context to switch to another set of policies when httpd starts?
3. Is it just a matter of making a copy of the httpd binary and change its selinux context that uses all new policies (relabel the httpd binary, but I'm sure it will take more than this)?
4. What are the steps to copy the existing httpd selinux settings to a new name?

I think this comes down to needing a httpdpublic and httpdprivate selinux context. Anyone done anything like this before that could give some guidance or suggest alternative solutions?  Thanks